# Install Wix Toolset 3.9 for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix, wix3.9

I have downloaded **Wix Toolset v3.9 R2 (Stable)** from http://wixtoolset.org/releases/ and installed it on my Windows 10 machine. **Visual Studio 2015** Ultimate is installed. I open my Soultion in VS and in the Solution Explorer I want to add a Wix Project. But there is no Wix Project available:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason that you're not using the latest version, Wix 3.10.2?

Wix 3.9 RC2 was made available on 2014/07/22, which is probably why it doesn't show up in 2015.  You'll probably need to use VS2013 if you specifically need Wix 3.9

Edit: [Manually configure VS2015 for older Wix versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26110644/2000111)

Comment: Yes, there is a reason.

Comment: Ok, well 3.9 isn't built for VS2015, either use an environment that supports 3.9 or try to manually configure 2015 for 3.9.