# How to import existing WIX project to a new solution in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, wix

I'm trying to migrate existing projects from Visual Studio 2010 to a new solution in VS 2015. I've been importing the csproj files easily by right clicking the solution> add> existing project...

Now I need to import an existing wixproj to my new solution, and can't seem to find a simple way to achieve this. Even when I try to search for all project types, the wixproj extension isn't listed.

I would rather not hack the solution file unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: Have you installed the latest version of the WiX toolset?

Comment: No I hadn't. This appears to have resolved my problem. Although I didn't want to install the latest version. I just found the following post which explains how to integrate older versions of the WiX toolset to VS2015: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110643/how-to-enable-wix-projects-in-visual-studio-2015 

Please mark your response as the answer to my question.